# How to limit by id a query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I want to make a limit with respect to id like this:

```
My table:

id   id_propertie   description
------------------------------
 1       1           Some text
 2       1           Some text
 3       2           Some text
 4       2           Some text
 5       2           Some text
 6       3           Some text
------------------------------
```

I want this

```
SELECT * FROM propertie limit 2


id   id_propertie   description
------------------------------
 1       1           Some text
 2       1           Some text
 3       2           Some text
 4       2           Some text
 6       3           Some text
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the easiest way is to use variables:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@id = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@id := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from propertie p cross join
           (select @id := 0, @rn := 0) params
      order by id_propertie, id
     ) p
where rn <= 2;
```

Comment: thanks bro i don't know that can use variables in sql